# How to center multiple images in scrollview in Xcode/Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to horizontally center 30 images in a scrollview. What is the best approach to do so? Thanks.

[image]

EDIT: Programmatically I was able to create the images, thanks to David Cao, but I am still having the issue of it not centering. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: the best approach is to use a UICollectionView not a ScrollView with a gazillion of images ;)

Comment: Yes, but because I wish to modify the individual images I would like to use scrollview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem. I modified David Cao's code to account for various screen widths using

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width`
```

I adjusted the scrollView frame size width to equal the screenWidth. Removing the border variable fit my need for fitting the screen perfectly.

```
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width
    //let screenHeight = screenSize.height

    let numWidth: CGFloat = 3
    let numHeight: CGFloat = 10
    self.scrollView.frame.size.width = screenWidth
    let width: CGFloat = (self.scrollView.frame.size.width - (numWidth + 1))/3

    for var i:CGFloat = 0; i < 3; ++i{
        for var j:CGFloat = 0; j < 10; ++j {

            let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "image1.png")!
            imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
            imageView!.frame = CGRectMake(width*i, width*j, width, width)
            self.scrollView.addSubview(imageView!)

        }
    }
    scrollView.contentSize.height = (width)*numHeight
```

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 2):

If they're all the same image, why not do this programmatically? Just make a for loop and iterate through the bounds.

```
NSInteger numWidth = 3;
NSInteger numHeight = 10;
CGFloat border = 8;
CGFloat width = (self.scrollView.frame.size.width - (numWidth + 1) * border)/3;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < numWidth; ++i) {
    for (NSInteger j = 0; j < numHeight; ++j) {
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageNameHere"]];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(border + width*i, border + width*j, width, width);
        [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    }
}
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width, (border + width)*numHeight + border];
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to apply your code. However the content continues not to center. See my above edit. Thanks.